# How to replace last character in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I need to write a command where the appearance of the last character depends on whether the same command immediately (except for any kind of whitespace) follows again or text appears in between.

The following minimum working example does what I want by not outputting the last character of the previous command until I tell it to - except that I always have to remember mentioning `\Finish` or the output gets broken, so I'd like some way that is less fragile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\@tmp{}

\newcommand\test[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tmp}{#2}}{}{\@tmp{}}%
    #1%
    \def\@tmp{#2}%
}

\newcommand\Finish{\@tmp{}\def\@tmp{}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\test{1}{2}\test{1}{2}\Finish{} (output: 112)

\test{1}{2}\test{3}{4}\Finish{} (output: 1234)

\test{1}{2}\test{3}{4} (output: 123 - missing 4 because I forgot Finish)

\test{5}{6}\Finish (output: 456 - the missing 4 showed up here.)

\end{document}
```

Comment: do these commands always come in pairs?  If yes, then perhaps use a boolean to set `true` when in the first instance and `false` after the second instance has been completed.

Comment: It would probably be more helpful if you could explain why you want your macros to behave in this manner.  It seems to me that one macro should probably suffice (or an environment or something).

Comment: You talk about *immediately* following, but you have no examples of what happens when there's intervening text.  Also, you talk about the "same command" follows, but you're testing on the contents of the first argument.  Which is it that should be tested:  the matching of the first argument of the macro, or just the matching of the macro call itself?

Comment: No, they don't always come in pairs but in an arbitrary number (1 or more). // Yes, an environment would work - but it would be like writing `\begin{Finish}\test{1}{2}\test{3}{4}\end{Finish}` which means I still have to remember writing it, so there's no gain over using `\Finish`. // What do you mean? In my example in the third line the text `(output: 123 - missing 4 because I forgot Finish)` intervenes before the next line `\test{5}{6}`. The second question I don't get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will produce the output you want.  But I think this could be much better if you clarified a bit about what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{first_of_two}

\makeatletter

\def\@tmp{}

\newcommand\test[2]{%
  \@ifnextchar\test
  {\@first@of@two@test{#1}{#2}}
  {\@singleton@test{#1}{#2}}%%
}

\def\@first@of@two@test#1#2{%%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tmp}{#2}}{}{\@tmp}%%
  \booltrue{first_of_two}%%
  \def\@tmp{#2}%%
  #1}

\def\@singleton@test#1#2{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \ifbool{first_of_two}
    {\let\ae@continue\@preceded@by@same}
    {\let\ae@continue\@singleton@isolated}%%
  \boolfalse{first_of_two}%%
  \ae@continue{#1}{#2}%%
  \def\@tmp{}%%
}

\def\@preceded@by@same#1#2{%%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tmp}{#2}}{#1#2}{\@tmp#1#2}\boolfalse{first_of_two}}

\def\@singleton@isolated#1#2{#1#2}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{1}{2}   \test{1}{2} (output: 112)

\test{2}{3} a  \test{2}{3} (output: 23a 23)

next line: 12:354

\test{1}{2}\test{3}{4}\test{5}{4}    (output: 1234)

\test{1}{2}\test{3}{4}    (output: 1234 - no missing 4 just because I forgot Finish)

\test{5}{6}               (output is not: 456 - no missing 4 showing up here.)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Going to try that.

Comment: @user66554 I've modified the code slightly to handle the case where there are more than 2 tests concatenated.

Comment: Oops. Given that I gave a minimal working example I omitted that the command is never called directly but always within another, so `\@ifnextchar\test` is never true because the next command has not yet been expanded. If it helps: the containing commands have a limited set of prefixes depending on their nesting depth, let's say they are `\def\testA{\test{1}{2}}`, `\def\testB{\test{3}{4}}` etc. and `\ndef\listoftestA{\testA\testB}`. Otherwise I'll presumably have to give to each of them a `\@ifnextchar`-case...

Comment: @user66554 The nice things about `\@ifnextchar` is that it gobbles up following white space, which seemed to be a prerequisite for you:  I would suggest you post a second question about how to make this work if the macros you want to work with are embedded within other macros.